# Pass data using JSON and retrieve it in view page

Tags: php, json, zend-framework

This is a part of my controller,i need to pass the data in the variable $coinPacks into my view page

---

```
else {
            $coinPacks=$packs->getPacks();
            // print_r($coinPacks);
            echo $this->_helper->json(array('error'=>array('error_code'=>300,'error_message'=>'No enough coins to do correction.','pack'=>$coinPacks)));
        }
```

---

here is the view page part

---

```
alert(JSON.stringify(response.error));
         // foreach($pack as $newpacks)
         // {

            answerContent = answerContent + '<p class="buy-coins" value="1" coins="100">200 &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; $1</p><p>';
            answerContent = answerContent + '<p class="buy-coins" value="3" coins="500">500 &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; $3</p><p>';
            answerContent = answerContent + '<p class="buy-coins" value="5" coins="1000">1000 &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; $5</p><p>';
            answerContent = answerContent + '<p class="buy-coins" value="15" coins="5000">5000 &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; $15</p><p>';
          // }
```

---

i need to get the values that passes from the view and use the value to make loop and display the corresponding value from the database.i really don't have much knowledge in json.please give me some advice.

---

am getting an alert like this

---

```
{"error":{"error_code":300,"error_message":"No enough coins to do correction.","pack":{}}}
```

Comment: first, check the value of $coinPacks Zend_Debug::dump($coinPacks); it seems its not valid value for json response.

Comment: @konradwww when using that it showing response like this <pre>object(Zend_Db_Table_Rowset)#147 (10) {
  [&quot;_data&quot;:protected] =&gt; array(4) {
    [0] =&gt; array(3) {
      [&quot;id&quot;] =&gt; string(1) &quot;1&quot;
      [&quot;number_of_coins&quot;] =&gt; string(3) &quot;100&quot;
      [&quot;price&quot;] =&gt; string(4) &quot;1.00&quot;

Comment: try first convert it to array with $coinPacks->toArray()

Comment: great! i've paste it as an answer below.

Answer (score 1):

try first convert it to array with `$coinPacks->toArray()`

Answer (score 0):

converted it into an array

---

```
   $coinPacks=$packs->getPacks();
                $coinpacks = array();
                foreach($coinPacks as $coin){
                    $coinpacks['id'] = $coin->id;
                    $coinpacks['number_of_coins'] = $coin->number_of_coins;
                    $coinpacks['price'] = $coin->price;
                    $coins[] = $coinpacks;
                }
```

---

and call it in the view page

```
  var coin = response.pack;                                                                                                                 

  for(var i=0;i<coin.length;i++)                                                                                               
  {                                   
      answerContent = answerContent + '<p class="buy-coins" value="'+coin[i].price+'" coins='+coin[i].number_of_coins+'>'+coin[i].number_of_coins+' &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; $'+coin[i].price+'</p><p>';                  
  }
```

---

> Now its working good